# Analogy to B-tree of order 5

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I'm trying to understand the relation between B-tree and Black Red Tree. As I've read a great tutorial [here](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_rbtree.aspx), I'm having a hard time to map a B-tree of order 5 to RB tree. Could you give an example? Probably I haven't grasp the essence of this data structure.

Thanks in advance and credits to the author of tutorial - Julienne Walker.

Comment: You can map B-trees of order 3 onto red/black trees, but you probably wouldn't map a B-tree of order 5 onto a red-black tree. You could use something like a red/black/blue tree (not a commonly-used data structure) to represent a B-tree of order 5, though.

Comment: @templatetypedef, Indeed more colors are needed to map a higher order B-tree. I should've read wikipedia more carefully. Thank you very much!!